# Does the presence of high level trainers have an effect on low level ones?

Tags: pokemon-go

I finally got my wife to play and I've noticed she is seeing many more different types of Pokemon despite just starting. When I started I primarily saw Rattata's and Pidgey's.

It appears that we see and can catch the same creatures, and I know that the rarity of present Pokemon increases as you go up in level. So I'm wondering, has the fact that I'm level 7 made it easier for her to catch different types of Pokemon?

Comment: Good question, I'm curious also

Comment: Even after surpassing level 10 long ago 90% of my encounters are still Ratatas and Pidgeys and depending on my location a fair amount of Drowzees. I don't think the pure presence of other trainers has an influence on this. If that would be the case you would probably encounter a lot of rare Pokémon on train stations and other populated areas.

Comment: I think you're right about the duplicate. Both speak to nearby trainers levels affecting spawns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really  isn't enough data to say either way yet.

Personally I think higher levels do attract a better quality pokemon to the area (thus anyone can catch it-but you need the high level to trigger it's spawn.)

Just personal experience but could be completely RNG

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience and that of people I know, your level affects the CP value of Pokemon you encounter, not necessarily the Pokemon themselves. So, if one of you is level 15 and the other is level 5, you will both encounter the same Pokemon in the same locations, but the level 15 might encounter a CP 500 while the level 5 might encounter a CP 50.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is enough to confirm it but a post does state that rarer pokemon appear the higher level you are: http://www.forbes.com/sites/davidthier/2016/07/12/how-to-find-rare-pokemon-in-pokemon-go/#14fd4e764cbb

From personal experience I am also inclined to agree but keep in mind more populated areas also tend to have more pokemon variety. As to answer your question directly everyone sees the same pokemon near them so I do believe that your presence does actually have some effect but it should still be rather minimal. I don't know if a pokemon have a minimal CP level but if they do and the minimal CP level is above the max CP level a trainer can see then she shouldn't be able to see it, but that's just speculation.